# Xamarin : Could not install package Parse 1.7.0

Tags: xamarin, parse-platform

I am currently working on a cross-platform app with Xamarin and I am trying to use the NuGet package [Parse 1.7.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/parse), but when I try to install the package via NuGet on Visual Studio 2015, I get this error :

```
Could not install package 'Parse 1.7.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Is it to understand the Parse official package is not compatible with Xamarin ? If so, is there a way to make it compatible ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside the `nupkg` of this package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/parse

You will find a `lib` folder with the following targets available. Thus you are trying to target Profile259, but there is no definition in the Parse NuGet package for this. That is why it fails. You must install against one of these targets instead.

[image]

Thus if you installed this individually into `MonoAndroid` or `Xamarin.iOS10`, it work install just fine (**Xamarin.Android** and **Xamarin.iOS** projects respectfully).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same, just remove the Silverlight platform from your targets and it should work